# Generate PDF with base64 encode string

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am using an API which provides me base64 encoded content. It is mentioned that we can download the PDF file by saving the content to a .pdf file.

In the API documentation, it's clearly mentioned

> A PDF that contains the contents of the invoice. You encode the
> content with a Base64 string to create a Base64-encoded .pdf file.
>
> You can query this field to download the invoice PDF for a specific
> invoice. After you query it, you can save the string to a .pdf file,
> then view the file in any PDF reader.

I am using TCPDF to write the content in PDF file. But it generates a blank PDF file.

> $PDF = new PDF('Test Title', 'Test Subject');
>
> $PDF->GetTCPDF()->write(0, 0, '', '',
> base64_decode($this->Get(self::Body)), 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
>
> $PDF->Download();

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: it seems you don't need to create pdf again, because base64_encoded data act as a real pdf file content. try my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should use this code to get your pdf file :

```
$data = base64_decode($this->Get(self::Body));
file_put_contents('mypdf.pdf',$data);
```

Then you can open it.

Or you can echo the content to your page like this :

```
$data = base64_decode($this->Get(self::Body));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $data;
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The last time I get a blank PDF I forgot adding a new Page with AddPage().
Apart from this I think M2sh is right.